# For completely programmatically created UIView/UIViewController, what should be in loadView vs viewDidLoad?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

For experimentation purposes, I am trying something completely in code.

I have a custom root `UIView`/`UIViewController` subclass pair called RootView and RootViewController respectively.

I also have a `GLKView`/`GLKViewController` subclass pair called RenderView and RenderViewController.

Both `UIViewController` subclasses create their managed views in their `loadView` overrides.

Setting up the main RootViewController/RootView is simple.  In my AppDelegate subclass, I create the main window and assign the  rootViewController proeprty like so...

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "RootViewController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
        CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

     // Set up the window
        UIWindow* mainWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:screenBounds];
        mainWindow.rootViewController = [RootViewController new];
        self.window = mainWindow;

        [mainWindow makeKeyAndVisible];

        return YES;
    }

@end
```

The RootView appears on screen exactly as one would expect.

What I'm wondering however is about view hierarchy initialization. RootViewController has a property to hold an instance of RenderViewController, and its RenderView will be (initially) placed in the frame which is stored in a second property of RootViewController called renderViewFrame.

My question is where is the proper place to set up that hierarchy?

The documentation states that's exactly what `UIViewController`'s `loadView` is for so this is what I'm doing there...

```
- (void)loadView
{
    self.view = [[RootView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

 // Set up the RenderViewController
    RenderViewController* renderViewController = [RenderViewController new];
    [self addChildViewController:renderViewController];

    renderViewController.view.frame = self.renderViewFrame;
    [self.view addSubview:renderViewController.view];

    self.renderViewController = renderViewController;
}
```

...and it works, but I've seen some people say no, I should move everything relating to creating RenderView/RenderViewController to RootViewController's `viewDidLoad` and not `loadView`, but no one can say why. I mean it is part of the hierarchy and that's specifically what `loadView` is for.

And if I'm right, then why would I/anyone need to use `viewDidLoad` at all if we're already doing initialization in `loadView`, or is that just an artifact from when memory could unload the views all the way back in iOS6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is fine for a completely programmatic solution. Since you do need to implement `loadView` you can as well do all the initialization here.

You *can* do a mixed `loadView` and `viewDidLoad` solution (only set the `view` property in `loadView`, do the rest in `viewDidLoad`); it might make it easier to go to a NIB/story board solution later on. Having the initialization in one place only (just `loadView`) might be easier to maintain than having it split in two (`loadView` and `viewDidLoad`). On the other hand, most people would expect to see a `viewDidLoad` method. As you can see, it's mostly a matter of taste.

When using XIBs or story boards, then of course it's recommended to avoid touching `loadView` at all and you thus should only implement `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Based on that, I think what I'm after can be better clarified using an IBoutlet as an example.  My setting of the RenderViewController property is equivalent to what IB would be doing with an outlet.  So where does IB set those outlets... loadView, viewDidLoad or between the two?

Comment: Mostly in `loadView` though IIRC some things are done later than that, can't remember what now though (perhaps I'm thinking of `awakeFromNib`)

Comment: Huh, good question… I actually don't know right now, either. I was going to write almost exactly the same comment as Wain.

Comment: Point being by the time it gets to viewDidLoad, all the outlets are connected, right?  if so, I'm fine leaving everything in loadView as I have it now as that seems like it would be the most portable should I switch to IB/Storyboard.  In that case I'd simply delete the loadView function and connect it up through IB. (Not quite 100% as I'd still have to position the view, but still.)

Comment: I think what it comes down to is 'Anything that would've been configured in IB, if you're now doing it programmatically, do it in loadView.'  Anything else that you're initializing in code, leave in 'viewDidLoad'. Sound about right?

Comment: I think as long as you're consistent across the project the approach is fine

Answer (score 1):

Apples documentation actually says just to load the view on `loadView` and do nothing else, then

> If you want to perform any additional initialization of your views, do so in the viewDidLoad method.

Technically both approaches will work, it's just about separating concerns and putting logic where it most makes sense and is expected to be found.

If the method was `loadViewHierarchy` then fill your boots. In 99.9999...% of all apps the additional views will be added (in a NIB or) in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: See my comment to @DarkDust's answer.